# Durability not shown even not after using items for a while

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

OS: Windows 10 Home Edition

Java: 1.8.0_121-b13

Since today I noticed that while I use my items the durability bar is  still slowly emptying but when I hover over the item it only shows the name, enchantments and damage/speed but not how many durability points are left.

I tried to save and exit as well as restarting the game but no change.
I'm at version 1.14.4 and have been so for the past few days at least but it still worked up to today. I haven't modified the game either (installing/removing mods, etc.) however I noticed yesterday evening that all my settings where back to default. I set them back to how they were before. Could this be due to a patch that has been downloaded and installed? If so how could I find out? If not what could the reason be otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>F3</kbd> and <kbd>H</kbd> will toggle the "Durability" feature on your equipment.

[image]

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_durability#Interface)

This will show 2 numbers; the items current amount of "uses", and the total uses this piece of equipment has. This will change depending on the item's quality (wood vs diamond), but enchantments will *not* affect this. Instead, they will randomly lose durability over time.

> Items with an Unbreaking enchantment do not always lose durability when used; for a given enchantment level, the chance that they will use durability is 1 in (1+level). The result is that they will last an extra level times their original durability, give or take a few.

[Source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_durability#Tool_durability)